# Bash nested conditionals show unexpected behavior

Tags: bash

please take a look at this:
This should echo X10, but echoes jackpot... can anyone see why it doesn't behave as it should?
Probably just some mistake I made that do not throw errors?

```
dice1=1
dice2=40

#These two lines are just tests to see if my brain still function:
echo "Is dice 1 less than 2? $(($dice1 < 2))"
echo "Is dice 2 between 6 and 54? $(($dice2 > 5 && $dice2 < 55))"

if [[ $dice1 == 1 ]]
then
        if [[ $dice2 < 6 ]]
        then
                #dice1 has to be equal 1 and dice2 less than 6:
                echo "jackpot"
        else
                #Since dice2 is larger than 5, if smaller than 55
                #it should be between 6 and 54...
                if [[ $dice2 < 55 ]]
                then
                        echo "X10"
                else
                        echo "X5"
                fi
        fi
else
        echo "Dice one is not equal 1."
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used with `[[`, the `<` and `>` operators sort lexicographically using the current locale.

I see two options.

Do the comparison in arithmetic context:

```
if (( $dice1 == 1 ))
then
    if (( $dice2 < 6 ))
```

or the old-fashioned way:

```
if [[ $dice1 -eq 1 ]]
then
    if [[ $dice2 -lt 6 ]]
```

Comment: @DanielZArt You're welcome. `if [[ $dice2 < 55 ]]` should also be changed in the same way btw.

Comment: Yep, worked like a charm. Did the arithmetic option, thanks man! Helped a lot. As you can probably tell I'm quite new to bash. Now I'll try to find where I upvote your answer.

Comment: Well, to this day I wasn't give the option to accept the solution Ted Lyngmo gave me. So maybe I'm too green on the site for such luxuries. Still grateful for the help though!